# How to serialize/deserialize enums in/from a lower case in Ktor?

Tags: kotlin, ktor, json-serialization

I use **Ktor serialization** in my app, below is a dependency in **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-serialization:$ktor_version"
}
```

And set up it in **Application.kt**:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

@Suppress("unused")
fun Application.module(@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") testing: Boolean = false) {
    // ...
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(Json {
            prettyPrint = true
        })
    }
    // ...
}
```

All works perfectly but enumerations... For example, I have the next one:

```
enum class EGender(val id: Int) {
    FEMALE(1),
    MALE(2);

    companion object {
        fun valueOf(value: Int) = values().find { it.id == value }
    }
}
```

If I will serialise this enum instance, **Ktor** will output a something like:

```
{
    "gender": "MALE"
}
```

**How to make it in a lower case without renaming enumeration members?**

**P.S.** Also I can't change `Int` to `String` type cuz it represents database IDs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the [SerialName](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization/-serial-name/index.html) annotation for enum constants to override names in JSON:

```
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
enum class EGender(val id: Int) {
    @SerialName("female")
    FEMALE(1),
    @SerialName("male")
    MALE(2);

    companion object {
        fun valueOf(value: Int) = values().find { it.id == value }
    }
}
```